Need Help Improving My ABC Algorithm Flowchart in TikZ (After Many Attempts)
I’m working on a project that requires creating a flowchart for the Artificial Bee Colony (ABC) algorithm using TikZ in LaTeX. However, I’m struggling with getting the boxes aligned, avoiding overlaps, and ensuring the arrows are well-measured and easy to follow.
I’ve tried my best to put together a diagram, but the result still isn’t quite right. As you can see in the image, some boxes overlap, and the arrows aren’t as clean or aligned as I’d like them to be. I really want to create a professional-looking, readable diagram, but my TikZ skills are limited, and I could use some guidance.
What I’ve Tried So Far:
I’ve set up blocks for each phase of the algorithm (employed bee, onlooker bee, scout bee).
I’ve added arrows to represent the flow, but they’re not aligned well, making it hard to read.
I experimented with different styles for boxes and arrows, but the final result still looks cluttered.
My Goal:
I’d love some help with:
Organizing the blocks more clearly, with consistent spacing.
Aligning the arrows to make them straight and readable.
Avoiding overlaps between boxes to improve clarity.
I’ve put a lot of time into this diagram, and I’d be so grateful if someone could guide me through the adjustments or even help improve the code directly. I’m eager to learn, so any tips or explanations would be extremely helpful!
Thank you so much in advance for your time and assistance
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 2cm, every node/.style={font=\small}]
    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!20]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow!20]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

    % Nodes
    \node (start) [startstop] {Initialisation of ABC parameters};
    \node (employedBee) [process, below of=start, yshift=-1cm] {Employed Bee Phase};

    % Steps within Employed Bee Phase
    \node (placeBee) [process, right of=employedBee, xshift=5cm] {Place all bees on model solutions};
    \node (evaluate) [process, below of=placeBee, yshift=-0.5cm] {Evaluate fitness of solutions};
    \node (returnBee) [process, below of=evaluate, yshift=-0.5cm] {Return to hive with report};
    \node (bestFit) [process, below of=returnBee, yshift=-0.5cm] {Calculate best fitness};
    \node (applyFitness) [process, below of=bestFit, yshift=-0.5cm] {Apply fitness function};
    \node (assignBee) [process, below of=applyFitness, yshift=-0.5cm] {Assign bee to employed bee phase};
    \node (update) [process, below of=assignBee, yshift=-0.5cm] {Update position based on best solution found};
    \node (employedDecision) [decision, below of=update, yshift=-0.5cm] {All employed bees?};

    % Onlooker Bee Phase
    \node (onlookerBee) [process, below of=employedBee, yshift=-6cm] {Onlooker Bee Phase};

    % Steps within Onlooker Bee Phase
    \node (calcProb) [process, right of=onlookerBee, xshift=5cm] {Calculate probability \( p_i \)};
    \node (selectSource) [process, below of=calcProb, yshift=-0.5cm] {Select food source based on probability};
    \node (compareBest) [process, below of=selectSource, yshift=-0.5cm] {Compare and update the best position};
    \node (onlookerDecision) [decision, below of=compareBest, yshift=-0.5cm] {All onlooker bees?};

    % Scout Bee Phase
    \node (scoutBee) [process, below of=onlookerBee, yshift=-3.5cm] {Scout Bee Phase};
    \node (abandon) [decision, left of=scoutBee, xshift=-4cm] {Abandon food source?};
    \node (generateNew) [process, below of=abandon, yshift=-0.5cm] {Generate new solution for scout bee};

    % Stopping Criteria
    \node (stopping) [decision, below of=scoutBee, yshift=-1.5cm] {Criterion satisfied?};
    \node (final) [startstop, below of=stopping, yshift=-0.5cm] {Final best solution};

    % Arrows
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (employedBee);
    \draw [arrow] (employedBee) -| (placeBee);
    \draw [arrow] (placeBee) -- (evaluate);
    \draw [arrow] (evaluate) -- (returnBee);
    \draw [arrow] (returnBee) -- (bestFit);
    \draw [arrow] (bestFit) -- (applyFitness);
    \draw [arrow] (applyFitness) -- (assignBee);
    \draw [arrow] (assignBee) -- (update);
    \draw [arrow] (update) -- (employedDecision);
    \draw [arrow] (employedDecision.east) -- ++(0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (onlookerBee);
    \draw [arrow] (employedDecision.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee);

    \draw [arrow] (onlookerBee) -| (calcProb);
    \draw [arrow] (calcProb) -- (selectSource);
    \draw [arrow] (selectSource) -- (compareBest);
    \draw [arrow] (compareBest) -- (onlookerDecision);
    \draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.east) -- ++(0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (scoutBee);
    \draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (onlookerBee);

    \draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (stopping);
    \draw [arrow] (stopping) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (final);
    \draw [arrow] (stopping.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.west);

    \draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -| (abandon);
    \draw [arrow] (abandon) -- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (generateNew);
    \draw [arrow] (generateNew) |- (scoutBee);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Current result when replacing class article by standalone:


don't use \tikzstyle. it's deprecated. substitute with \tikzset.

er ... what size paper are you using? ;)

You load the positioning library but don't really use it as far as I can see.

I find the easiest way to create this kind of diagram is to first create a structure where you can at least see everything. One relatively straightforward way of doing this is to use a \matrix. The matrix library lets us create one as a matrix of nodes, which provides a more convenient syntax and additional customisation options.
I'd also recommend switching to arrows.meta, as arrows use deprecated syntax, and ext.paths.ortho for additional varieties of orthogonal paths.
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning,matrix,ext.paths.ortho}

You can remove positioning if you don't use it elsewhere as this solution doesn't need it.
\tikzstyle is deprecated. Either just use [] or use \tikzset. Here, the former works fine.
Configuration changes:
    every node/.style={font=\small\sffamily,fill opacity=.25,draw opacity=1,text opacity=1,},
    shader/.style={top color=#1!20,bottom color=#1,middle color=#1!50},

Diagrams usually look better with sans fonts, especially if you need to reduce the text size. The colouring I amended last and I suggest you do the same. The original colouring was a bit 'flat', so the idea is to use just a bit of shading. You don't want the shading to distract from the content, but a little bit can add a slight sense of depth and sometimes improves the overall appearance (imho).
    % Define block styles
    startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text width=5cm, minimum height=7.5mm, anchor=base, text centered, draw=black, shader=black},

Unless you are working on A3 pages or something, the original dimensions are simply too large once you spread things out enough to make them visible. You could spread horizontally a bit, but there's no entirely obvious way of doing that in non ad hoc fashion, so I tried to make things more compact instead. This is still rather high/deep, so you might need to adjust further, but this would fit on an otherwise empty page (i.e. no header/footer), which can work well for whole page diagrams if used sparingly.
    process/.style={rectangle, text width=5cm, minimum height=7.5mm, anchor=base, text centered, draw=black, shader=blue},

We're adding partial opacity to the fill, so we don't need to thin the colour down for blue. We set a standard text width so we get nicely aligned boxes, regardless of the actual text width.
    decision/.style={diamond, text width=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt, align=center, draw=black, inner color=magenta!50,outer color=magenta, anchor=center},

I couldn't make yellow work in a way I liked, so I substituted magenta. A deeper golden yellow would also work, I think.
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=Stealth},

arrows.meta provides Stealth rather than stealth. Now for the matrix itself. We can the matrix abc which will allow us to refer easily to each of its cells by abc-<row>-<column>. I set the vertical separation to 5mm. More might look better, but it would add too much height. We're less pressed horizontally, so we can use the 2cm there.
  \matrix (abc) [matrix of nodes,row sep=5mm,column sep=20mm]
  {%

A \matrix is a rather fancy node. So all the content goes inside curly brackets as usual, \matrix (<name>) [<options>] {<content>};. The only difference is that <content> itself consists of nodes. The basic syntax is the standard tabular or array syntax, but with a few twists.
    & |[startstop]| Initialisation of ABC parameters & \\

This specifies the first row. There are three cells. The first and third are empty. The second is equivalent to \node [startstop] {Initialistion of ABC parameters};. So we can lay out the rows quite straightforwardly.
    & |[process]| Employed Bee Phase & |[process]| Place all bees on model solutions \\
    & & |[process]| Evaluate fitness of solutions \\
    & & |[process]| Report back to hive \\

This isn't what you wrote originally. When trying to make a diagram fit, think about whether a more concise text can convey the same information. Regardless of space, short, label-like contents tend to work better than long, sentence-like contents. You are in the best position to judge what is essential, what is equivalent and what should be highlighted. My changes are simply suggestions from somebody who has no idea what this diagram is intended to communicate or who it is intended to communicate its message too. You should be able to do rather better than I can hope to!
    & & |[process]| Calculate best fitness \\
    & & |[process]| Apply fitness function \\
    & & |[process]| Assign bee to employed bee phase \\
    & & |[process]| Use best solution to update position \\
    & & |[decision]| All employed bees? \\

I tried to keep Phase nodes in the middle column and particular steps in the far column. I don't know if these groupings have the significance I assigned to them, but, if not, try to think of a spatial structure which will reflect something meaningful.
    & |[process]| Onlooker Bee Phase & |[process]| Calculate probability \( p_i\) \\
    & & |[process]| Select most probable food source \\
    & No & |[process]| Compare \& update best position \\
    & & |[decision]| All onlooker bees? \\[-10mm]

I added the Yes/Nos as nodes in the matrix, too.
    & Yes & \\
    No & |[process]| Scout Bee Phase & \\
    & |[decision]| Criterion satisfied? & |[decision]| Abandon food source? \\

However, I could not quite figure out how it was all supposed to work: in some cases, there does not seem to be a second pathway ....
    & Yes &  Yes \\
    & |[startstop]| Final best solution & |[process]| Generate new solution for scout bee \\
  };

Now for the arrows. Because we named the matrix, we didn't bother to name the individual nodes. I used three \foreach <variables> in {<list>} {<stuff to do>; for the arrows.
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially 1-2)] in {%
    2-2/--,2-3/--,3-3/--,4-3/--,5-3/--,6-3/--,7-3/--,8-3/--,9-3/--,10-2/-|,10-3/--,11-3/--,12-3/--,13-3/--%
  }
  \draw [arrow] (abc-\ilast) \j (abc-\i) ;

This loop uses two variables. The first variable, \i, is remembered from the previous loop. Since the first loop doesn't have a previous one, we specify a starting value for that case. This loop draws a string of arrows where each node is connected to the next and we don't need to adjust the anchors or deal with much branching. The second variable, \j, specifies how to draw the path between each node and the remembered one. This could be -- or |- or -| or, since we loaded ext.paths.ortho, something like |-|. (See the library's manual for several additional possibilities.)
  \foreach \i/\j/\k  in {%
    14-2/15-2/--,12-2/10-2/--,%
    16-3/17-3/--,17-3/18-3/--,18-3.west/15-2.355/-|-,15-2/16-2/--,17-2/18-2/--,15-1/2-2/|-%
  }
  \draw [arrow] (abc-\i) \k (abc-\j) ;

This loop draws all the remaining arrows. \i is the first node, \j is the second and \k specifies the kind of path to construct. Notice the use of -|- from that extra library and the specification of anchors in abc-18-3.west (the west anchor of the third cell in the eighteenth row of abc) and 15-2.355 (found by trial and error to accommodate arrows to and from the eastern side of the same node).
  \foreach \i/\j/\k  in {%
    13-3/12-2/-|-,13-3/14-2/-|,%
    16-2/15-1/-|,16-2/17-2/--,15-2.5/16-3/-|%
  }
  \draw  (abc-\i) \k (abc-\j) ;

This loop draws lines without arrows because I placed the Yes/No as nodes rather than labels on paths. Note that abc-15-2.5 is the destination for that second arrow accommodated by the 355 anchor in the previous loop.

Complete code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning,matrix,ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730211/
    node distance=2cm and 2cm,
    every node/.style={font=\small\sffamily,fill opacity=.25,draw opacity=1,text opacity=1,},
    shader/.style={top color=#1!20,bottom color=#1,middle color=#1!50},
    % Define block styles
    startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text width=5cm, minimum height=7.5mm, anchor=base, text centered, draw=black, shader=black},
    process/.style={rectangle, text width=5cm, minimum height=7.5mm, anchor=base, text centered, draw=black, shader=blue},
    decision/.style={diamond, text width=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt, align=center, draw=black, inner color=magenta!50,outer color=magenta, anchor=center},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=Stealth},
  ]
  \matrix (abc) [matrix of nodes,row sep=5mm,column sep=20mm]
  {%
    & |[startstop]| Initialisation of ABC parameters & \\
    & |[process]| Employed Bee Phase & |[process]| Place all bees on model solutions \\
    & & |[process]| Evaluate fitness of solutions \\
    & & |[process]| Report back to hive \\
    & & |[process]| Calculate best fitness \\
    & & |[process]| Apply fitness function \\
    & & |[process]| Assign bee to employed bee phase \\
    & & |[process]| Use best solution to update position \\
    & & |[decision]| All employed bees? \\

    & |[process]| Onlooker Bee Phase & |[process]| Calculate probability \( p_i\) \\
    & & |[process]| Select most probable food source \\
    & No & |[process]| Compare \& update best position \\
    & & |[decision]| All onlooker bees? \\[-10mm]

    & Yes & \\
    No & |[process]| Scout Bee Phase & \\
    & |[decision]| Criterion satisfied? & |[decision]| Abandon food source? \\

    & Yes &  Yes \\
    & |[startstop]| Final best solution & |[process]| Generate new solution for scout bee \\
  };
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially 1-2)] in {%
    2-2/--,2-3/--,3-3/--,4-3/--,5-3/--,6-3/--,7-3/--,8-3/--,9-3/--,10-2/-|,10-3/--,11-3/--,12-3/--,13-3/--%
  }
  \draw [arrow] (abc-\ilast) \j (abc-\i) ;

  \foreach \i/\j/\k  in {%
    14-2/15-2/--,12-2/10-2/--,%
    16-3/17-3/--,17-3/18-3/--,18-3.west/15-2.355/-|-,15-2/16-2/--,17-2/18-2/--,15-1/2-2/|-%
  }
  \draw [arrow] (abc-\i) \k (abc-\j) ;

  \foreach \i/\j/\k  in {%
    13-3/12-2/-|-,13-3/14-2/-|,%
    16-2/15-1/-|,16-2/17-2/--,15-2.5/16-3/-|%
  }
  \draw  (abc-\i) \k (abc-\j) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Very good approaches and suggestions +1

Just want to show an example. IMHO, this is a better organized layout for this diagram according to your approach.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm and 2cm,
% Define block styles 
startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!20},
process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10,text width=3cm},
decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow!20},
arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth}
]

% Nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Initialisation of ABC parameters};
\node (employedBee) [process, below=of start] {Employed Bee Phase};

% Steps within Employed Bee Phase
\node (placeBee) [process, below right=of employedBee] {Place all bees on model solutions};
\node (evaluate) [process, below=of placeBee] {Evaluate fitness of solutions};
\node (returnBee) [process, below=of evaluate] {Return to hive with report};
\node (bestFit) [process, below=of returnBee] {Calculate best fitness};
\node (applyFitness) [process, below=of bestFit] {Apply fitness function};
\node (assignBee) [process, below=of applyFitness] {Assign bee to employed bee phase};
\node (update) [process, below=of assignBee] {Update position based on best solution found};
\node (employedDecision) [decision, below=of update] {All employed bees?};

% Onlooker Bee Phase
\node (onlookerBee) [process, below=of employedBee] {Onlooker Bee Phase};

% Steps within Onlooker Bee Phase
\node (calcProb) [process, below left=of onlookerBee] {Calculate probability \( p_i \)};
\node (selectSource) [process, below=of calcProb] {Select food source based on probability};
\node (compareBest) [process, below=of selectSource] {Compare and update the best position};
\node (onlookerDecision) [decision, below=of compareBest] {All onlooker bees?};

% Scout Bee Phase
\node (scoutBee) [process, below right=of compareBest,yshift=-0.6cm] {Scout Bee Phase};
\node (abandon) [decision, above=of scoutBee] {Abandon food source?};
\node (generateNew) [process, above=of abandon] {Generate new solution for scout bee};

% Stopping Criteria
\node (stopping) [decision, below=of scoutBee] {Criterion satisfied?};
\node (final) [startstop, below=of stopping] {Final best solution};

% Arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (employedBee);
\draw [arrow] (employedBee.south) --++(0,-0.5) -| (placeBee);
\draw [arrow] (placeBee) -- (evaluate);
\draw [arrow] (evaluate) -- (returnBee);
\draw [arrow] (returnBee) -- (bestFit);
\draw [arrow] (bestFit) -- (applyFitness);
\draw [arrow] (applyFitness) -- (assignBee);
\draw [arrow] (assignBee) -- (update);
\draw [arrow] (update) -- (employedDecision);
\draw [arrow] (employedDecision.east) -- ++(1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee);
\draw [arrow] (employedDecision.west) -- ++(-1,0) |-node[anchor=south] {Yes} (onlookerBee);

\draw [arrow] (onlookerBee.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (calcProb);
\draw [arrow] (calcProb) -- (selectSource);
\draw [arrow] (selectSource) -- (compareBest);
\draw [arrow] (compareBest) -- (onlookerDecision);
\draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.east) -- ++(1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (scoutBee);
\draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (onlookerBee);

\draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (stopping);
\draw [arrow] (stopping) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (final);
\draw [arrow] (stopping.west) -- ++(-7.8,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.west);

\draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (abandon);
\draw [arrow] (abandon) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (generateNew);
\draw [arrow] (generateNew.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) |- (scoutBee.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

To answer your question in the comment

I think the style and layout are more likely personal opinion based. I really don't like the overlap of lines in this type of diagram. So if you want add a no feedback to the first phase, then I will propose another layout. However, it doesn't has absolute correct answer here. All depends on your preference.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm and 2cm,
% Define block styles 
startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!20},
process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10,text width=3cm},
decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow!20},
arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth}
]

% Nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Initialisation of ABC parameters};
\node (employedBee) [process, below=of start] {Employed Bee Phase};

% Steps within Employed Bee Phase
\node (placeBee) [process, below right=of employedBee] {Place all bees on model solutions};
\node (evaluate) [process, below=of placeBee] {Evaluate fitness of solutions};
\node (returnBee) [process, below=of evaluate] {Return to hive with report};
\node (bestFit) [process, below=of returnBee] {Calculate best fitness};
\node (applyFitness) [process, below=of bestFit] {Apply fitness function};
\node (assignBee) [process, below=of applyFitness] {Assign bee to employed bee phase};
\node (update) [process, below=of assignBee] {Update position based on best solution found};
\node (employedDecision) [decision, below=of update] {All employed bees?};

% Onlooker Bee Phase
\node (onlookerBee) [process, below=of employedBee] {Onlooker Bee Phase};

% Steps within Onlooker Bee Phase
\node (calcProb) [process, below=of onlookerBee] {Calculate probability \( p_i \)};
\node (selectSource) [process, below=of calcProb] {Select food source based on probability};
\node (compareBest) [process, below=of selectSource] {Compare and update the best position};
\node (onlookerDecision) [decision, below=of compareBest] {All onlooker bees?};

% Scout Bee Phase
\node (scoutBee) [process, left=of compareBest,yshift=-0.6cm] {Scout Bee Phase};
\node (abandon) [decision, above=of scoutBee] {Abandon food source?};
\node (generateNew) [process, above=of abandon] {Generate new solution for scout bee};

% Stopping Criteria
\node (stopping) [decision, below=of scoutBee] {Criterion satisfied?};
\node (final) [startstop, below=of stopping] {Final best solution};

% Arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (employedBee);
\draw [arrow] (employedBee.south) --++(0,-0.5) -| (placeBee);
\draw [arrow] (placeBee) -- (evaluate);
\draw [arrow] (evaluate) -- (returnBee);
\draw [arrow] (returnBee) -- (bestFit);
\draw [arrow] (bestFit) -- (applyFitness);
\draw [arrow] (applyFitness) -- (assignBee);
\draw [arrow] (assignBee) -- (update);
\draw [arrow] (update) -- (employedDecision);
\draw [arrow] (employedDecision.east) -- ++(1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee);
\draw [arrow] (employedDecision.west) -- ++(-1,0) |-node[anchor=south] {Yes} (onlookerBee);

\draw [arrow] (onlookerBee.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (calcProb);
\draw [arrow] (calcProb) -- (selectSource);
\draw [arrow] (selectSource) -- (compareBest);
\draw [arrow] (compareBest) -- (onlookerDecision);
\draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| node[anchor=north] {Yes} ([xshift=0.5cm]scoutBee.east) --  (scoutBee.east);
\draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (onlookerBee);

\draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (stopping);
\draw [arrow] (stopping) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (final);
\draw [arrow] (stopping.west) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.172);

\draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (abandon);
\draw [arrow] (abandon) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (generateNew);
\draw [arrow] (generateNew.west) -- ++ (-0.5,0) |- (scoutBee.west);

\draw [arrow] (abandon.east) -- ++(0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.188);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your help! I still have a small issue here (\draw [arrow] (abandon.west) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.west);) the arrow doesn’t look quite right in the figure. Could you suggest how I can position it, or do you think it’s acceptable as it is?

@farah See the changes in the answer.

very neat suggestions! maybe a different colour for the 'phase' nodes if they are at a different 'level' than the other process nodes?

@cfr good suggestion.

Here is some refactoring to get you going. I won't finish the connections by now, but will put a few more elucidations a bit later. (Done)
1. Refactoring
See it as the process of reshaping your code without changing its output, besides removing overlaps etc. I noted down the relevant steps.
More can be done, once the structure is easier to handle (and is as intended). E.g. I would introduce some font={...} options together with align= statements to improve the process-boxes here and there. (One of my personal drivers is to make the code easy to grasp (its structure) WITHOUT actually reading it  (knowing WITHOUT knowing)
You'll become more flexible via class standalone, once you do your drawing in this class and use e.g. article in your main document. See, how to do it, e.g. here, e.g. the PI-controller.
2. Styles
common abstracts some common options you used, while the rest just use them amongst others.
3. Placement
I must admit, to a large extent I used best-guess which box goes where. Basis step here is to move from positioning to matrix (you can vary its layout a bit, see manual).
Syntactically think of matrix as tabular, which introduces the & separators and CRLF (so to say) at the end \\.
As you can see in the pgfmanual in one of the tutorials you simply place (named) nodes in a table-like structure. It would be a bit easier to digest if I'd split it like this, simply because it will be easier to grasp:
\matrix {
  & coordinate (start) & ;\\
...
};   % all positioned in terms of coordinates

% ~~~ now have nodes at the coordinates ~~~~~
\node at (start) {start-content};
...


4. Connections
Once named nodes or coordinates are placed as intended it's pretty straight forward, almost as you tried it. Both from a time constraint and my guessworking on the node positions I didn't activate all of them. Shouldn't be too much of a challenge now.
5. Some layout considerations
I would-

first do the standalone graphic
include it in my main document for control purposes
adjust width, fonts etc. to enhance read-ability in the main document.

E.g. it would be nicer to have equally wide boxes (common). Perhaps font={\large}, may be a good add-on etc.

% ~~~ REFACTORING ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%
%   1.  rewriting styles, i.e. abstracting common options
%   2.  replacing positioning by (tikz) matrix
%       in parallel: trying to streamline code a bit more clear
%   3.  modifying decision style a little; deleting text centered

%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%node distance=2cm and 2cm, every node/.style={font=\small},
    % Define block styles
    common/.style       = {rectangle, draw=black,minimum height=1cm,},
    startstop/.style    = {rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,common,fill=gray!20},
    process/.style      = {minimum width=3cm,common, fill=blue!10},
    decision/.style     = {common, diamond, minimum width=3.5cm,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm,align=center},
    arrow/.style        = {thick,->,>=stealth}
    ]
    % ~~~ using a matrix; think of tabular syntax, in TIKZ terms ( & & ... & \\) placing nodes
    \matrix [row sep=5mm]{
    % Nodes
    &\node [startstop]      (start)             {Initialisation of ABC parameters};&\\
    &\node [process]        (employedBee)       {Employed Bee Phase};&
        \node [process]     (placeBee)          {Place all bees on model solutions};\\
%       
    &\node  [process]       (onlookerBee)       {Onlooker Bee Phase};
        &\node [process]    (evaluate)          {Evaluate fitness of solutions};\\
    &\node [process]        (calcProb)          {Calculate probability $p_i$};
        &\node [process]    (returnBee)         {Return to hive with report};\\
    &\node [process]        (selectSource)      {Select food source based on probability};
        &\node [process]    (bestFit)           {Calculate best fitness};\\
    &\node [process]        (compareBest)       {Compare and update the best position};
        &\node [process]    (applyFitness)      {Apply fitness function};\\
    &   &\node [process]    (assignBee)         {Assign bee to employed bee phase};\\
    &   &\node [process]    (update)            {Update position based on best solution found};\\
    &\node [decision]       (onlookerDecision)  {All onlooker bees?};
        &\node [decision]   (employedDecision)  {All employed bees?};\\
%    
    \node [decision]        (abandon)           {Abandon food source?};
      &\node [process]      (scoutBee)          {Scout Bee Phase}; &\\
     \node [process]        (generateNew)       {Generate new solution for scout bee};
        &\node [decision]   (stopping)          {Criterion satisfied?};&\\
    &\node [startstop]      (final)             {Final best solution};\\
};

%    % Arrows
    \draw [arrow] (start)           -- (employedBee);
%    \draw [arrow] (employedBee) -| (placeBee);
    \draw [arrow] (placeBee)        -- (evaluate);
    \draw [arrow] (evaluate)        -- (returnBee);
    \draw [arrow] (returnBee)       -- (bestFit);
    \draw [arrow] (bestFit)         -- (applyFitness);
    \draw [arrow] (applyFitness)    -- (assignBee);
    \draw [arrow] (assignBee)       -- (update);
    \draw [arrow] (update)          -- (employedDecision);
%    \draw [arrow] (employedDecision.east) -- ++(0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (onlookerBee);
%    \draw [arrow] (employedDecision.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee);
%
%    \draw [arrow] (onlookerBee) -| (calcProb);
    \draw [arrow] (calcProb) -- (selectSource);
    \draw [arrow] (selectSource) -- (compareBest);
    \draw [arrow] (compareBest) -- (onlookerDecision);
%    \draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.east) -- ++(0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (scoutBee);
%    \draw [arrow] (onlookerDecision.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (onlookerBee);
%
%    \draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -- (stopping);
%    \draw [arrow] (stopping) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (final);
%    \draw [arrow] (stopping.west) -- ++(-0.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (employedBee.west);
%
%    \draw [arrow] (scoutBee) -| (abandon);
%    \draw [arrow] (abandon) -- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (generateNew);
%    \draw [arrow] (generateNew) |- (scoutBee);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


